# Assign function argument to global variable of the same name

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, scope

Is it possible to set a global variable from within a function that takes that same variable name as an argument?

```
var a:int = 0;
function test(a:int)
{
    a *global* = a *local*;
}
test(1);
trace(a) // traces 0 but I'd like it to trace 1
```

(The reason why I'd like to do this, is to avoid constantly coming up different variables names for the same things)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont do so. You dont avoid problems - you'll build some new... Use e.g. prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to it explicitly as `this.a = a;` in your function `test`
In this case `this` is the class instance that holds this variable. In case of a `static` variable, you can use `ClassName.a = a`.